# Question about the booleans in expl3 (of LaTeX3)

Tags: expl3

In `expl3`, there are the commands `\int_zero_new:N`, `\tl_clear_new:N`,  `\str_clear_new:N` , `\seq_clear_new:N`, `\clist_clear_new:N`, etc., but there is no similar command for the booleans (something like `\bool_false_new:N`). Is there a reason ?

Comment: @TeXnician But isn't the objective to make a new one, or to set an existing false?

Comment: The objective of such a command would be to set the boolean to false... after creation of this boolean if it doesn't yet exist. Of course, it's very easy to write such a command. My question is: why such an command doesn't since it would be very similar to the existing commands for many other `expl3` types of objects.

Comment: The default value of a new boolean is false.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer. Yes, I know but this is not my question.

Comment: I think it would make sense to provide such a command.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I agree.

Comment: @egreg Thinking some more, I am not sure: we have `\int_zero:N` and `\int_zero_new:N`, but we don't have `\bool_false:N`, we have `\bool_set_false:N`, so it should be `\bool_set_false_new:N` I guess.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Choosing names always leaves some doubt. One could also discuss about `\tl_clear(_new):N`, because the variable is set to empty value, which is not the same as having no value. Only boxes can have no “value”, so `\box_clear:N` is appropriate (but this is perhaps hair splitting). Maybe `<var type>_reinitialize:N` could encompass all the cases, but…

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind that `expl3` is under very active development and no “final” version exists yet.  That is to say, that the reason for the absence of commands like `\bool_false_new:N` is that nobody has implemented them yet.  This is usually due to the fact that nobody was able to come up with a convincing use-case.  The LaTeX3 team is rather reluctant with adding new functionality for which there are few or no users, out of fear that `expl3` becomes too bloated and unmaintainable.  Nevertheless, you should feel encouraged to file a pull request against the official `expl3` upstream code at https://github.com/latex3/latex3 such that a discussion about this new feature can be created.